# Is it possible to compose two interfaces and duck type a class to the composition?

Tags: c#

I have a class that inherits from `ObservableCollection<T>` to re-use the `INotifyCollection` functionality, but acts like a `HashSet`. I've called it `ObservableHashSet<T>`. I use both `ObservableCollection` and `ObservableHashSet` in my app.

I've reached a point where I want to pass either an `ObservableCollection` or an `ObservableHashSet` into a method, but the only functionality I'm interested in is `IEnumerable<T>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

My question is: is it possible to have a single method that takes as its parameter either of these classes? i.e.

```
ObservableCollection<IExample> a = new ...
ObservableHashSet<IExample> b = new ...
MyMethod(a);
MyMethod(b);
```

I'm using .NET 4, in case there are any juicy features in there that are useful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've inherited from `ObservableCollection` then using that as the parameter type should work.

Comment: Ah, I think I've over simplified my example: It should be ObservableHashSet<Example> where Example implements IExample.

I'm getting a compile error when I try and do this: cannot convert from ObservableHashSet<Example> to ObservableCollection<IExample> where Example implements IExample. I'm really sure why though... covarience issue perhaps.

Comment: Yes, that's a covariance/contravariance issue, and that's a much less trivial problem.  You should maybe update your question (and/or read the multitude of other answers on the subject).

Answer (score 3):

I've found a nice solution, use a generic method and constrain the type parameter with the two interfaces I need:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T collection) where T : IEnumerable<IExample>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
}
```

This seems to do the trick nicely. I'd welcome any comments on doing it this way though :)

Comment: I'd suggest Dan's solution, unless there is more to the issue than you mentioned. There's no need to use generics if simple interface polymorphism will do.